# The probability of winning a certain lottery is 28% . If I wish to participate in the lottery 6 times what are my odds of winning?

Tags: probability

So I have 28% chance of winning a lottery and I can participate 6 times in the lottery what are my odds of winning it . How to add these kinds of probabilities . How much do the odds increase if I participate 8 times

Comment: $1-(1-0.28)^6$.

Comment: and for the second question $(1-0.28)^8-(1-0.28)^6$

Comment: ^ Salute to Both of you 

Comment: @aras It´s wrong $1-(0.72)^8-(1-0.72^6)=0.72^6-0.72^8$

Comment: @aras $(1-0.28)^{8}-(1-0.28)^6< 0$ so it is the opposite you shoud have written.

Comment: odds is $p/(1-p)$ where $p$ is probability

Comment: @DacianBonta What do you mean ?

Comment: the question asks about odds of winning, not the probability of winning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways that you might win. Assuming that you don't enter the lottery again once you win, the possible ways that you could win are (if the probability of winning is $p$):

You win on the first go, probability $p$

You lose on the first go and win on the second go, probability $(1-p)p$

You lose on the first two goes but win on the third go, probability $(1-p)^2p$

You lose on the first three goes but win on the fourth go, probability $(1-p)^3p$

You lose on the first four goes but win on the fifth go, probability $(1-p)^4p$

You lose on the first five goes but win on the sixth go, probability $(1-p)^5p$

The total probability of winning with 6 goes, $P_6$, is just the sum of the probabilities of all the ways you might win:
$$
P_6 = \left[1+(1-p)+(1-p)^2+...+(1-p)^5 \right]p
$$
This involves a geometric series, which we can sum by employing the well-known formula
$$
\sum_{n=0}^N x^n = \frac{1-x^{N+1}}{1-x}
$$
$$
\implies P_6 = \frac{1-(1-p)^6}{1-(1-p)}p = \frac{1-(1-p)^6}{p}p = 1-(1-p)^6
$$
Of course, you can immediately generalise to the probability of winning after $M$ goes:
$$
P_M = 1-(1-p)^M
$$
Interestingly, if you take the limit $M \to \infty$, you are certain to win eventually if you keep entering an unlimited number of times!

Answer (score 0):

If we note $\mathbb{P}[\text{losing}]$ the probability to lose when participating at one game, the probability to lose $n$ times is given by
$$\mathbb{P}[\text{losing}]^{n}$$
because we suppose it is independent. Since the probability to win at least one time is the complementary event to lose at each game, the probability to win when playing $n$ times is

$$1-\mathbb{P}[\text{losing}]^{n}$$

Here, $\mathbb{P}[\text{losing}]=1-\mathbb{P}[\text{winning}]=1-0.28=0.72$ and $n=6$. It gives:

$$1-\mathbb{P}[\text{losing}]^{n}=1-(1-0.28)^{6}=1-0.72^{6}\approx 0.86$$

If you play $m>n$ times, your odds increase by:

$$(1-\mathbb{P}[\text{losing}]^{m})-(1-\mathbb{P}[\text{losing}]^{n})=\mathbb{P}[\text{losing}]^{n}-\mathbb{P}[\text{losing}]^{m}$$

Here, it gives

$$(1-0.28)^6-(1-0.28)^{8}\approx 0.067$$

Answer (score 0):

You can win the lottery in many ways.  You lose (=not win) only if you lose every single time. But, you either win or not win.  So, the probability that you win is 1-(probability you do not win).  That applies to both 6 trials and to the single trial.  So

$P_n = 1-(1-P_0)^n$

where $P_n$ is success after n tries and $P_0$ is success after one try.

Odds is $p/(1-p)$ where $p$ is probability, so the odds after n tries is:

$Odds_n = (1/(1-P_0)^n)-1$